# AzureAD Audit Logs CorrelationID - Returns two entries with the same correlation ID but different Directory_ID

Tags: azure-active-directory

We have a dynamic user group, users are added to this group automatically based on department. I wanted to check a particular audit log, I used PowerShell to get the audit log using correlationId and it returned two values with a different Audit ID but same correlationID. I assumed that correlationId's are unique per activity.

```
Value 1:
id: Directory_f606e2f6-4f88-43bb-8172-83e945533d1f_6LW2D_26019271
correlationId:f606e2f6-4f88-43bb-8172-83e945533d1f
targetResources:  {id=9f9ee398-e2d2-4e5b-949f-7e79ce0087c0}

Value 2:
id: Directory_f606e2f6-4f88-43bb-8172-83e945533d1f_6LW2D_26019272
correlationId:f606e2f6-4f88-43bb-8172-83e945533d1f
targetResources:  {id=9f9ee398-e2d2-4e5b-949f-7e79ce0087c0}
```

please assist me if you have come across this situation.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment.***

Commands:

```
$logs=Get-AzureADAuditDirectoryLogs  -All $true
$logs.CorrelationId
```

[image]

Commands:

```
$logs=Get-AzureADAuditDirectoryLogs  -top 10
$logs.CorrelationId
write-host "Id" 
$logs.Id 
write-host "CorrelationId"
$logs.CorrelationId
write-host  "  "
```

Output:

[image]

**`Even for different directory audit logs , correlation Id seems same for the next coming audits of related  event .`**

***It is because each of the audit logs has and “ID” and “CorrelationID  where this  correlation ID is useful in  finding related audit events.The audit events have  same correlation ID.***

***It suggests the child events are taking the parent correlation Id in order to  find out or investigate  the originating events or its related events.***

Also  check the limitation in the given reference

**Reference :** [azure-devops-auditing · GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/blob/main/docs/organizations/audit/azure-devops-auditing.md)